# NodeJS Express Rest API tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Hello everyone I am new in NodeJS environment . I want to develop a API based application using NodeJS, MongoDB and Express JS. I need a complete api development tutorial where I learn route, middleware , mongoose one to many and many to many feature and nodeJS login system . Basically I need a complete package of tutorial about NodeJS rest api development

Comment: Here is the link [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oXYLzuucwE&list=PL55RiY5tL51q4D-B63KBnygU6opNPFk_q] to learn Nodejs Express JS, MongoDB, Middleware etc from this tutorial. I'm also new to node js platform. It's easy to learn from these tutorials.

Comment: You may be want to look into this tool which do the work quickly to start. https://codecanyon.net/item/nodejs-automatic-api-generator-from-mysql-database-ultimate-edition/25033454

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out the Reddit API Clone by [Dev Coffe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5Nle1VXYnw) and the Nodejs tutorials from [LearnCode.academy](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGAACzU6GliHJDp4kmOw3NFsh).

There are also several paid courses on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=nodejs&src=ukw) and [Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/q:mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample service.Create a file structure in a suitable way.
Code given below is a code of complete service.
Also refer express documentations for furthur knowledge

**server.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const cors=require('cors');
const routing=require('./routes');
const app=express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use('/',routing);

app.listen(8095,'localhost',err=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
   console.log('connected to localhost at post 8095');
});
```

**routes.js**

```
const express=require('express');
const routes=express.Router();
const bookroute=require('./Books/controllers/book.controller');
const authorroute=require('./Books/controllers/author.controller');

routes.use('/books',bookroute);
routes.use('/authors',authorroute);

module.exports=routes;
```

**controllers->author.controller**

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const authorModel=require('../models/author.model');

router.get('/',authorModel.getAuthors);
module.exports=router;
```

**controllers->book.controller**

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const bookModel=require('../models/book.model');

router.get('/',bookModel.getBooks);
router.get('/authors',bookModel.getAutBooks);
router.get('/:name',bookModel.getBook);
router.post('/',bookModel.addBooks);
router.delete('/:name',bookModel.deleteBooks);

module.exports=router;
```

**models->author.model**

```
var schema=require('../dbSchema');
var authormodel=schema.model('author');


exports.getAuthors = function (req,res) {
    authormodel.find().exec().then((data)=>{
        res.send(data)
    })
};
```

**models->book.model**

```
var schema=require('../dbSchema');
var bookmodel=schema.model('book');

exports.getBooks = function (req,res) {
    bookmodel.find().exec().then((data)=>{
        res.send(data)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
};

exports.getBook = function (req,res) {
    var bkName=req.params.Author;
    bookmodel.find({Name:bkName}).exec().then((data)=>{
       res.send(data)
    }).catch((err)=>{
       console.log(err);
   }   );
 };

exports.getAutBooks = function (req,res) {
bookmodel.find({},'Author').then((data)=>{
     res.send(data);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});
};

   exports.deleteBooks=function(req,res){
   var bkName=req.params.name;
   bookmodel.remove({Name:bkName}).exec().then((data)=>{
      res.status(200);
      console.log(bkName);
   }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});
};

exports.addBooks=function(req,res){
var newBook=new bookmodel({
    Name:req.body.Name,
    ISBN:req.body.ISBN,
    Author:req.body.Author,
    Price:req.body.Price,
    Year:req.body.Year,
    Publisher:req.body.Publisher
});
newBook.save().then(()=>{
    res.status(201);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});
};
```

**dbchema**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const schema=mongoose.Schema;

const bookSchema=new schema({
    Name:{type:String,required:true},
    ISBN:{type:String,required:true},
    Author:{type:String,required:true},
    Price:{type:String,required:true},
    Year:{type:String,required:true},
    Publisher:{type:String,required:true}

});

const authorSchema=new schema({
    fname:{type:String,required:true},
    lname:{type:String,required:true},
    nationality:{type:String,required:true}
});

mongoose.model('book',bookSchema,'booklist');
mongoose.model('author',authorSchema,'authorlist');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbFinal',(err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
});

   module.exports=mongoose;
```